# SQL Server Insert Query problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I want to execute this query :

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (FactorId, ProductId, Entity) 
VALUES((SELECT Top 1 FactorId FROM Factor WHERE UserId = @UserId AND Status = -1), @ProductId, @Entity)
```

but the following error occurs :

> Subqueries are not allowed in this
>   context. Only scalar expressions are
>   allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (FactorId, ProductId, Entity) 
SELECT Top 1 FactorId, @ProductId, @Entity FROM Factor WHERE UserId = @UserId AND Status = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (FactorId, ProductId, Entity) 
SELECT (select Top 1 FactorId FROM Factor WHERE UserId = @UserId AND Status = -1), 
@ProductId, @Entity
```

Comment: I executed this query, but the following error occurs:

The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (FactorId, ProductId, Entity) 
(SELECT Top 1 FactorId, @ProductId, @Entity FROM Factor 
WHERE UserId = @UserId AND Status = -1)
```

Note : insert query with select wont allow **VALUES** keyword :) .

Answer (score 0):

if you have other columns involved, avoid the TOP 1 altogether and consider something like this...

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (FactorId, ProductId, Entity) 
SELECT FactorId, @ProductId, @Entity FROM Factor 
WHERE UserId = @UserId 
  AND Status = -1
  and timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from Factor where UserId = @UserId AND Status = -1)
```

This concept also works if you have a sort-order column or any other unique column

Comment: There are other better answers. This is more complicated and has the risk of inserting multiples when max(timestamp) is not unique